# prevent regex errors with unpredictable values

Tags: google-apps-script

In a mail merge application I use the `.replace()` method to replace field identifiers by custom values and also in a reverse process to get the identifiers back.

The first way works every time since the replace first argument is a pretty normal string that I have chosen on purpose... but when I reverse the process it happens sometimes that the string contains incorrect regular expression characters.
This happens mainly on phone numbers in the form `+32 2 345 345` or even with some accentuated characters.

Given I can't prevent this from happening and that I have little hope that my endusers won't use this phone number format I was wondering if someone could suggest a workaround to escape illegal characters when they come up ? note : it can be at any place in the string.

below is the code for both functions.

```
    ... (partial code)
    var newField = ChampSpecial(curData,realIdx,fctSpe);// returns the value from the database
    if(newField!=''){replacements.push(newField+'∏'+'#ch'+(n+1)+'#')};
//Logger.log('value in '+n+'='+realIdx+'  >>  '+Headers[realIdx]+'  =  '+ChampSpecial(curData,realIdx,fctSpe))
    app.getElementById('textField'+(n+1)).setHTML(ChampSpecial(curData,realIdx,fctSpe));
    if(e.parameter.source=='insertInText'){
    body.replaceText('#ch'+(n+1)+'#',newField);
    }
  }
  UserProperties.setProperty('replacements',replacements.join('|'));
  cloakOn();
  colorize('#ffff44');
  return app;
}

function fieldsInDoc(e){
  cloakOff();// remet d'abord les champs vides
  var replacements = UserProperties.getProperty('replacements').split('|');
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  for(var n=0;n<replacements.length;++n){
    var field = replacements[n].split('∏')[1];
    var testVal = replacements[n].split('∏')[0];    
    body.replaceText(testVal,field);
    }
  colorize('#ffff44');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution was to prevent the example fields in the doc from containing regex special characters so the replace had to occur in the forward process, *not in the reverse* (as suggested in the other answer).
Escaping these character in the fields values didn't work* so I ended up with a simple replacement by a hyphen (which make sense in most cases to replace a slash or a '+').

(*) the reverse process uses the value kept in memory so the escape sign was disturbing the replace in that function, preventing it to work properly.

the final working code goes simply like this :

```
//(in the first function) 
    var newField = ChampSpecial(curData,realIdx,fctSpe).replace(/([*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "-");// replace every occurrence of *+?^... by '-' (global search)
```

About the comment stating that this approach is a bad idea I can only say that I'm afraid there is not really other ways to get that behavior and that the probability to get errors if finally quite low since the main usage of mail merge is to insert proper names, adresses, emails and phone numbers that are rarely in the template itself.

As for the field indicators they will never have the same name since they are numerically indexed (#chXX#).

**EDIT :** following Taras's comment I'll try another solution, will update later if it works as expected.

---

**EDIT June 19** *, Yesssss...  found it.*

I finally found a far better solution that doesn't use regular expression so I'm not forced to escape special characters ... the `.find()` method accepts any string. 
The code is a bit more complex but the results is worth the pain :-))

here is the full code in 2 functions if ever someone looks for something similar.

```
function valuesInDoc(e){
  var lock = LockService.getPrivateLock(); // just in case one clicks the second button before this one ends
  var success = lock.tryLock(5000);
   if (!success) {
     Logger.log('tryLock failed to get the lock');
     return
   }
  colorize('#ffffff');// this function removes the color tags on the field marlers
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
  var listVal = UserProperties.getProperty('listSel').split(',');
  var replacements = [];
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var find = body.findText('#ch');
  if(find == null){return app };
  var curData =   UserProperties.getProperty('selItem').split('|');
  var Headers = [];
  var OriHeaders = UserProperties.getProperty('Headers').split('|');
  for(n=0;n<OriHeaders.length;++n){
    Headers.push('#'+OriHeaders[n]+'#');
  }
  var fctSpe = 0 ;
  for(var i in Headers){if(Headers[i].indexOf('SS')>-1){fctSpe = i}}
  for(var n=0;n<listVal.length;++n){
    var realIdx = Number(listVal[n]);
  Logger.log(n);

    var newField = ChampSpecial(curData,realIdx,fctSpe);
//Logger.log(newField);    
    app.getElementById('textField'+(n+1)).setHTML(ChampSpecial(curData,realIdx,fctSpe));
    if(e.parameter.source=='insertInText'){
      var found = body.findText('#ch'+(n+1)+'#');// look for every field markers in the whole doc
      while(found!=null){
      var elemTxt = found.getElement().asText();
      var startOffset = found.getStartOffset();
      var len = ('#ch'+(n+1)+'#').length;
            elemTxt.deleteText(startOffset, found.getEndOffsetInclusive())
            elemTxt.insertText(startOffset,newField);// remove the marker and write the sample value in place
Logger.log('n='+n+'  newField = '+newField+'  for '+'#ch'+(n+1)+'#'+' at position '+startOffset)
  replacements.push(newField+'∏'+'#ch'+(n+1)+'#'+'∏'+startOffset);// memorize the change that just occured
        found = body.findText('#ch'+(n+1)+'#',found); //loop until all markers are replaced 

          }
        }
  }
  UserProperties.setProperty('replacements',replacements.join('|'));
  cloakOn();
  colorize('#ffff44');// colorize the markers if ever one is left but it shouldn't happen
  lock.releaseLock();
  return app;
}


function fieldsInDoc(e){
  var lock = LockService.getPrivateLock();
  var success = lock.tryLock(5000);
   if (!success) {
     Logger.log('tryLock failed to get the lock');
     return
   }
  cloakOff();// remet d'abord les champs vides > shows the hidden fields (markers that had no sample velue in the first function
  var replacements = UserProperties.getProperty('replacements').split('|');// recover replacement data as an array
Logger.log(replacements)
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  for(var n=replacements.length-1;n>=0;n--){ // for each replacement find the data in doc and write a field marker in place
    var testVal = replacements[n].split('∏')[0]; // [0] is the sample value
    if(body.findText(testVal)==null){break};// this is only to handle the case one click on the wrong button  trying to place markers again when they are already there ;-)
    var field = replacements[n].split('∏')[1];
    var testValLength = testVal.length;
    var found = body.findText(testVal);
    var startOffset = found.getStartOffset();
Logger.log(testVal+' = '+field+' / start: '+startOffset+' / Length: '+ testValLength)   
      var elemTxt = found.getElement().asText();
      elemTxt.deleteText(startOffset, startOffset+testValLength-1);// remove the text
//      elemTxt.deleteText(startOffset, found.getEndOffsetInclusive() )
      elemTxt.insertText(startOffset,field);// and write the marker
  }
  colorize('#ffff44'); // colorize the marker
  lock.releaseLock();// and release the lock
}
```

Comment: Your downside of your solution is the fact that you are changing the field values the users provide: A clear phone number like `+49 (89) 12345678` will show up as `-49 -89- 12345678`. Did you find some problem I was not aware of in my proposed solution?  BTW: the best solution for mail merge here is: iterate trough the document tree and grab the text elements with the replacement markers. Then replace the text with `.setText()`. The probability to get errors is then zero ;-)

Comment: *iterate trough the document tree* is a good Idea, I'll try that and update later. thx

Comment: You could try to apply a specific formatting, maybe a background color, to the field markers (#chXX#). I would expect this to isolate the markers into single text elements without the surrounding text, which will make the replace process much easier.

Comment: they already have a yellow background for visual confort ;-) could you suggest a piece of code to handle the search on color ?

Comment: Just curious Serge, is there any reason you need to "put the identifiers back"? Would it be unreasonable to just copy a template for each mail-out?

Comment: @AdamL Of course I do it :-) the 'put it back' is just there to allow the user to preview the result before creating all the docs and eventually bring some improvement /modification to the layout and/or to the database entries (doc creation might be a quite long process as you know :-)

Comment: btw the "real" part when I create the docs is actually very simple since I just have to replace the field markers with the database value  (or an empty string if no data is present) and my field markers have no special characters in it of course. Then you could answer 'why so much efforts for just a test ?' well, if we were not a bit fool we wouldn't be here discussing about javascript mysteries ! am I right ?

Comment: @AdamL You should be aware that there is a limit of 250 documents created with GAS **per day** so you don't want to waste your quota on test runs. And you would need to create a new document on each record you feed in, as there is a simple way to make a deep copy of the document ito a GAS object, but unfortunately I didn't find a practicable procedure to overwrite the document with the saved copy:-(

Comment: @Taras - I followed your suggestion (well aproximately, let's say 'a part of it') using the possibility in Google docs to manipulate text with indexed in elements... that's really much more reliable and doesn't change the format of the fields... thx for the headsup on this.

Answer (score 0):

In the reverse process you are using the fieldvalues provided that can include regex special characters. you have to escape them before replacing:

```
body.replaceText(field.replace(/[[\]{}()*-+?.,\\^$|#\s]/, '\\$&'), '#ch'+(n+1)+'#');
```

This said, the "replace back the markers" a bad idea. What happens if two fields of the mail merge have the same value or the replacement text is already present in the document template...