# Using GAS tools how could I differentiate find() results

Tags: google-apps-script

First of all I'd like to apologize for this question that is not exactly a GAS related question although in my opinion it is clearly a "programming" question in the context of Google Apps Script.

In a [recent post about string replacements in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145610/prevent-regex-errors-with-unpredictable-values/17163137#17163137) I found a quite reliable way to replace strings using the `find()` method and deleting/appending strings in textElements.
As I mentioned in this post the approach is very efficient, not disturbed by special characters and (quite) simple to implement.

So I was happy and spent some time to play with all kind of names and addresses and at some point I found an entry that made the search/replace process crash and messed up my document. It took me some time to find out the origin but I finally got it :

An example : someone called ***John*** living in a street called ***John Kennedy street***, when I look for ***John*** before looking for (and replacing by a #marker#) ***John Kennedy street***  I'm dead ! (way of speaking) because it will - depending on the sequence order - insert *John* (in fact it will replace John by the field marker corresponding to John) in place of  the one corresponding to *John Kennedy street* ...  and after that it will never find John Kennedy street anymore (the address field would be something like ***#marker# Kennedy street*** ***!!!***

So the question is :

- knowing that I know exactly all the fields that will be used
- knowing that the `find()` tool works always the same way iterating in the doc in the same direction
- knowing that I have a place to memorize any useful parameter along with the fieldnames and their replacement values
- considering that this process can be logically described (I tried my best) and that I can use any Gas specific or javascript method...

Knowing all that how can I handle this situation to prevent this error ?

I've been thinking about it over and over but I don't find any good idea...

How would you approach that problem ?

My best guess was that I could try to remember the place of each item in the document using the tree structure of Google docs and use that as a supplementary condition) but since this would be quite complicated ( there can be lots of different items in this doc : tables, paragraphs, lists...) I'd rather ask here beforehand because I would hate to work for nothing if there is something more simple that I didn't think of.

(thanks for reading this long post.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You realized what I did mean with "bad idea". As I wrote in the other entry, you have to iterate the document tree and grab the text elements that need to be substituted. The `.findText()` way is a nice shortcut which spares you the tree iteration but you forgot to grab and hold the text elements for later restore. I would get a list of all replacement tags first:

```
function jumpIntoSearchAndCollect(container, path, tagList) {
  for ( var i=0; i<container.getNumChildren(); i++ ) {
    var element = container.getChild(i);
    switch (element.getType) {
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH:
    // add all other container elements here, I'm too lazy
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE:
        jumpIntoSearchAndCollect(element, path.splice(-1,0,i), tagList);
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT:
        if (element.getBackgroundColor() == '#ffff44' && /^#.+#$/.test(element.getText()))
          tagList.push({element: element,
                        marker: element.getText().slice(1,element.getText().length-2),
                        path: path.splice(-1,0,i) };
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
  return;
}
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var tagList = [];
jumpIntoSearchAndCollect(body, [], tagList);
```

now you have to run the taglist and replace the text elements:

```
for ( var i=0; i<tagList.length; i++) {
  tagList[i].element
              .setBackgroundColor('#ffffff')
              .setText(textToTag(tagList[i].marker));
}
```

restoring the markers is simple:

```
for ( var i=0; i<tagList.length; i++) {
  tagList[i].element
              .setBackgroundColor('#ffff44')
              .setText('#' + tagList[i].marker + '#');
}
```

At this point you should ask: "Why did you store a property named 'path' with each replacement?" Well, your element pointers are lost if your script exits. Each time you reenter your script, you have to get your pointers back:

```
for (var i=0; i<tagList.length; i++) {
  tagList[i].element = restoreElementPointer( body, tagList[i].path);
}   

function restoreElementPointer (element, path) {
  if (path.length == 1) return element.getChild(path[0]);
  else return restoreElementPointer( element.getChild(path[0]), path.slice(1));
}
```

Hope I did't put too much typos in ;-)

PS: cross your fingers that Google Doc will not merge the text elements while your script is away since that they aren't highlited after replacement. But there is a way to account for that as well ...

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer. As I thought this approach is quite complicated but I'm going to give it a try. I'll update when I have a "final" code.

Comment: Also, thanks for taking the time to do this +Taras. Trying my best to work through and understand the recursive stuff. Regarding `path.splice(-1,0,i)`, doesn't this return an empty array (and therefore always set an empty array as the 'path' property)? Why not say `path.concat(i)`? I know I've probably missed something here, would be grateful if you could help out a noob. :-)

Comment: `path.concat([i])` is probably as good as `path.splice(-1,0,i)`. I used splice because I know that splice always returna a new deep copy of the array.